# SPSS - flag cases within a calendar month

Tags: spss

I have a list of prisoners and when their prison term started (PrisonStart) and when it ended (PrisonEnd). If they're still in prison, PrisonEnd is blank.

I would like to flag prisoners who were in prison at least one full calendar month during a 6-month period (1/1/16 to 5/30/16).

```
compute PeriodBeg = date.mdy(01,01,16).
compute PeriodEnd = date.mdy(05,30,16).
formats PeriodBeg PeriodEnd (adate10).
execute.
```

Any suggestions for how best to go about this? Seems I might need to compare prisoners' start and end dates separately for each month during the 6-month period (like below), and then select any prisoner with at least one full month, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way.

```
if ((PrisonStart le [January 1, 2016]) and (PrisonEnd ge ([January 31, 2016]) | missing(PrisonEnd))) InPrisonJan = 1.
if ((PrisonStart le [February 1, 2016]) and (PrisonEnd ge ([February 28, 2016]) | missing(PrisonEnd))) InPrisonFeb = 1.
etc.
execute.
```

Some sample data below. The first two prisoners should be flagged as having been in prison for at least one full calendar month during the 6-month period (OneMonth = 1). The last three prisoners were not in prison for at lease one full calendar month during the 6-month period (OneMonth = 0).

```
data list list /PrisonerID (F8.0) PrisonStart (adate10) PrisonEnd (adate10)    PeriodBeg (adate10) PeriodEnd (adate10).
begin data
1 10.3.14 7.12.16 1.1.16 5.30.16
2 2.9.16 4.1.16 1.1.16 5.30.16
3 5.2.16 10.11.16 1.1.16 5.30.16
4 12.1.13 2.8.14 1.1.16 5.30.16 
5 1.7.16 1.20.16 1.1.16 5.30.16
6 1.1.17 3.2.17 1.1.16 5.30.16
end data.
```

Comment: did you mean 1/1/16 to 6/30/16?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following syntax avoids mentioning the last day of each month separately, so it could be used to automate across any number of months. The trick to check if the date is the last day of the month, is by checking day "0" of NEXT month:

```
do repeat inpr=inPrison1 to inPrison5/ mon=1 to 5.
   compute inpr=( PrisonStart<=date.dmy(1,mon,2016) and 
                  (PrisonEnd>=date.dmy(0,mon+1,2016) or missing (PrisonEnd)) ).
end repeat.
```

Comment: I'm definitely missing something. Your code creates a variable lastMonth (filled with 0s), a variable frstMonth (filled with 1s), and 6 variables (inPrison1 ... inPrison6) filled with 0s. The need is to identify prisoners who were in prison at least one full calendar month (using their PrisonStart and PrisonEnd values) within the 6 month period (PeriodBeg and PeriodEnd).

Comment: I added some sample data to help illustrate the need.

Comment: OK now I see - we were using different variable names. See my updated version - now I also take into account dates before or after the period.

Comment: (I changed the 6s in your code to 5s since it's actually a 5-month period I've specified.) Either way, the code shows ID 4 was in prison for the 1st full month of the period, but he wasn't: he left prison 2 years (2/8/14) before the period started (1/1/16). I also added another case in the data for a prisoner who entered prison (1/1/17) after the 5-month period, and the code shows he was in prison every month. I don't see where the code is incorporating the year, which may explain the issue. I appreciate your continued help. I'll keep exploring it, too.

Comment: ok @Larry, you're right, the previous solution wasn't going well - I scratched it and put a much nicer one instead.

Comment: Very elegant! Thanks for all the help. I'm now trying to modify it to work for a 5-month period that crosses a year (e.g., 9/1/16 - 2/28/17), which I think may require a different approach. But your answer works for the data and example I provided, so thank you.

Comment: Start the loop like this: `do repeat inpr=inPr0916 inPr01016 .... inPr0217/mon=9 10 11 12 1 2/yr=2016 2016 2016 2016 2017 2017.` you can then build the dates inside the loop like this: `date.dmy(1,mon,yr)' and `date.dmy(0,mon+1,yr)`